# rails render partial template with collection not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

Found some similar answers, but no one seems to fit.
I also read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html, chapter 3.4.5, Rendering collections.

I'd like to render the following partial: (`users/_user_append.html.erb`)

```
<%= content_tag_for(:tr, user) do %>
  <td class="dim"><%= user.id %></td>
  <td><%= user.lastname %></td>
  <td><%= user.firstname %></td>
  <td><%= user.company %></td>
  <td><%= user.email %></td>
  <td class="fadeactions col-md-2">
    <%= link_to(content_tag(:i, nil, class: 'fa fa-minus-square-o'),
        remove_mailgroup_user_path(@mailgroup, user),
          :method => :delete, remote: true,
          :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
            toggle: "tooltip", title: "Remove user", placement: 'top'
          }
        )
     %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

The call for rendering looks like:

```
<%= render partial: 'users/user_append', collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

`...as: :user...` should pass the collection to the partial, as far I understand.
However, nothing appears in the browser.
Who finds the bug? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Where does table-tag begin? In some cases it is not possible to break table elements so much (I've had negative experiences with putting tables inside pdf through over-automating the table creation process for example). If you put random text inside this partial, will it be displayed?

Comment: Your syntax looks correct. Are you sure `@users` is not `nil`?

Comment: Yes, @user was nil...  Since I use a nested resource, I'd need to pass as follows:
`<%= render partial: '/users/user_append', collection: @mailgroup.users, as: :user %>`
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion we realised the problem was *not* in the way you call your partial, but rather in the way you defined the `@users`. As they weren't defined correctly, there was no way for the partial to receive the `:user` param.

The **solution** was to change

```
<%= render partial: '/users/user_append', collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

to

```
<%= render partial: '/users/user_append', collection: @mailgroup.users, as: :user %>
```

Comment: I already use the partial `_user.html.erb` for another slightly different rendering.

Comment: That was it! Since it's a nested resource, I need to pass @group.users as follows:
`<%= render partial: '/users/user_append', collection: @mailgroup.users, as: :user %>`. Thanks @TheChamp

Comment: Ok I updated my answer. I'll delete my comments, since they're noise and the solution is now included in the answer.